# Revisited: TClientDataset "Missing data provider or data packet"

Tags: delphi, firedac, tclientdataset, delphi-10.4-sydney

With a dynamically created `TFDQuery`,`TClientDataSet`, and `TDataSetProvider` I bump into the "Missing data provider or data packet" with this code:

```
procedure ResetSavedPasswords(ADataModuleDataBaseAdmin : TDataModuleDataBaseAdmin);
var
   lQuery     : TFDQuery;
   lCDS       : TClientDataSet;
   lProvider  : TDataSetProvider;
begin
   lFrmBezig := TFormBezig.Create(nil);
   lQuery    := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
   lProvider := TDataSetProvider.Create(Application); 
   lCDS      := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
   try
      lQuery.Connection := ADataModuleDataBaseAdmin.FDConnectionTimeTell;
      lQuery.CachedUpdates := true;
      lProvider.Options := lProvider.Options - [poUseQuoteChar];
      lProvider.DataSet := lQuery;
      lProvider.Name    := 'prvResetSavedPW';
      lCDS.ProviderName := lProvider.Name;
      lQuery.SQL.Text   := Format('select %s,%s from <owner>%s',[sMedMedID,sMedSavedPassword,SMedTabelNaam]),ADataModuleDataBaseAdmin;
      lCDS.Open;
```

Note that the created `TDataSetProvider` has an owner, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29989717/512728):

> If DatasetProvider has no owner, ClientDataSet can not obtain a reference to the provider

But I still get the error. Opening the `TFDQuery` first shows me it has data.

What can be the reason?

Using FireDAC with Delphi 10.4. Sydney in a Win32 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `TClientDataSet` needs an owner too:

```
lCDS := TClientDataSet.Create(Application);
```

This is obvious from the code that triggered the exception:

```
function TCustomClientDataSet.GetAppServer: IAppServer;
var
  ProvComp: TComponent;
  DS: TObject;
begin
  if not HasAppServer then
  begin
    if ProviderName <> '' then
      if Assigned(RemoteServer) then
        FAppServer := RemoteServer.GetServer
      else if Assigned(ConnectionBroker) then
        FAppServer := ConnectionBroker.GetServer
      else
      begin
        if Assigned(Owner) then
        begin
          ProvComp := Owner.FindComponent(ProviderName);
          if Assigned(ProvComp) and (ProvComp is TCustomProvider) then
          begin
            DS := GetObjectProperty(ProvComp, 'DataSet');
            if Assigned(DS) and (DS = Self) then
              DatabaseError(SNoCircularReference, Self);
            FAppServer := TLocalAppServer.Create(TCustomProvider(ProvComp));
          end;
        end;
      end;
    if not HasAppServer then
      DatabaseError(SNoDataProvider, Self);
  end;
  Result := FAppServer;
end;
```

The `Assigned(Owner)` fails, so the code does not bother looking for the `TDataSetProvider`